# Что означает автоматические ночные билды?

Tags: непрерывная-интеграция

Читаю [статью такую](https://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/) на хабре и тут вот есть такой абзац

> Ветвь origin/develop мы считаем главной ветвью для разработки. Хранящийся в ней код в любой момент времени должен содержать самые последние изданные изменения, необходимые для следующего релиза. Эту ветку также можно назвать «интеграционной». Она служит источником для сборки автоматических ночных билдов.

Что означает  автоматические ночные билды?

Comment: [Непрерывная интеграция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: @metalurgus я гуглил, но не совсем понял... Ваш комментарий кстати тоже не имеет отношения к конкретному вопросу

Comment: Имеет абсолютное отношение. Тем более, что @Qwertiy тоже так считает. Если бы я хотел *ответить* на ваш вопрос, я бы оставил *ответ*, а не комментарий.

Comment: @metalurgus ну пусть будет по вашему) Тем не менее ответ `ZigZag` мне понравился  и помог)

Comment: Комментарии созданы для *замечаний* и  *вопросов* к спрашивающему. Я сделал замечание.

Comment: @metalurgus, метку [tag:разработка] уже [выпилили](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3291/178988) :(

Comment: @metalurgus Спасибо, учтем пожелания)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это значит что у разработчиков построена система сборки продуктов, которая по определенному расписанию (в данном случае ночью) автоматически собирает очередную версию продукта. Одним из факторов, который говорит о зрелости компании разработчика программного обеспечения, является ее способность в любой момент собрать рабочую версию продукта. Обычно заливки делаются разработчиками в течении дня, ну а ночью идет автоматическая сборка. При этом к утру либо есть версия для тестировщиков, либо крашится система сборки и разработчики разбираются почему так произошло

Comment: "night build" это просто термин, это не обязательно значит "ночью", скорее -- когда большая часть команды не коммитит. у вас может быть команда по всему земному шару.

Comment: А по какой ветке идет билд? Просто исходя из статьи на хабре в ветке мастер всегда релизная рабочая версия... В верке девелоп +/- тоже... Так как если нужно внести изменения то создается еще ветка от девелоп которая называется фича и в ней уже работают... Следуя этим правилам какую ветку ставят на билд?

Comment: Билдят общую ветку разработчиков, куда они все коммитят или мержат. В терминологии SVN -- это trunk.

Comment: В данном вопросе одного ответа быть не может, так как может собираться и не один билд. Тут уже все индивидуально, какие "правила игры"в компании, насколько большой продукт, какой его жизненный цикл. Есть ли альфа, бета и т.п. версии продукта..Т.е. билд ставят в зависимости от того, какой вопрос с продуктом необходимо решить..выпустить в релиз, отдать на внешнее тестирование, отдать на внутреннее тестирование и т.п..

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko можно и несколько веток настроить на билд. А некоторые системы непрерывной интеграции умеют даже автоматически искать ветки и билдить их все. По поводу же того, какую ветку билдят в данном случае - в статье это написано, и даже цитату оттуда вы привели.

Answer (score 2):

Стоит отметить, что с удешевлением инфраструктуры, развитием инструментов для непрерывный интеграции и возросшей популярностью непрерывной поставки/развертывания, такое понятие как "ночной билд", уходит в прошлое. Потому как с т.з. быстроты обнаружения и исправления проблем, лучше всего запускать билды (в любой ветке) по коммиту. К тому же в случае использования непрерывной поставки/развертывания, это является необходимым условием.

Comment: При всей ценности этого сообщения, на вопрос оно, на мой взгляд, не отвечает.